# How to stop a user from opening a new browser session in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a front end document locking process that creates an Application Scope variable with the UNID/Username/time in it, then a timer that updates this information every 30 seconds. If someone tries opening the document to edit I check (using the UNID) to see if anyone else has the document. If the time is greater than 30 seconds I cancel the lock and allow the new user to open it.

I have considered do something similar with a database 'lock' which is pretty simple but I need a unique Identifier of the browser session. I can build the applicationScope variable using ReplicaID/UserName/time but I need one more piece of information that will identify this browser session.

Is there such a piece of information available somewhere? Something like a browser sessionID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to allow only **one** open browser window/tab per *user* and *database*.

For every XPage you open in browser you have to test if the same database is open in another browser window/tab already. If so, decline opening XPage with e.g. redirecting to an error XPage.

It is impossible to do this on server side only as the server don't know in which browser tab an Xpage gets opened.

So, the server needs client's help. The client have to give the server a **unique** browser **window/tab id**.

A browser window/tab doesn't have a unique id. But, opening a new window/tab we can create an *random id* and store it in browsers **[sessionStorage](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/)**. This is a unique storage for *every* window/tab.

This *window/tab id* can be send to server with a partial refresh GET and stored on server for the user in an application scope variable.

Also, the server has to know when a window/tab gets closed so that the same database can be opened in another window/tab. For this the client has to tell the server "I am alive" every X seconds.

**This is the complete solution:**

Create a Custom Control "UniqueBrowserTab"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var secondsIamAliveInterval = 5;
            var tabId = sessionStorage.getItem("tabId");
            if (!tabId) {
                tabId = Math.random();
                sessionStorage.setItem("tabId", tabId);
            }
            function sendTabIdToServer() {
                XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:browserTabControl}", {
                    params: {'tabId': tabId}
                });
            }
            sendTabIdToServer();
            setInterval(function() {
                sendTabIdToServer();
            }, secondsIamAliveInterval * 1000);
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:panel id="browserTabControl">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var secondsIgnoreOtherSession = 7;
            if (param.tabId) {
                var userName = session.getEffectiveUserName();
                var userData = applicationScope.get(userName);
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                if (userData) {
                    if (userData.tabId !== param.tabId) {
                        if (userData.time + secondsIgnoreOtherSession*1000 > now) {
                            context.redirectToPage("Error.xsp");
                        }
                    }
                } 
                applicationScope.put(userName, {tabId : param.tabId, time: now});
            }
            return true
        }]]></xp:this.rendered>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Include the Custom Control "UniqueBrowserTab" into every XPages or e.g. into application layout's Custom Control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xc:UniqueBrowserTab />
    ...
</xp:view>
```

Create an XPage Error.xsp wich has *not* included the Custom Control "UniqueBrowserTab".

This will allow only one browser window/tab per database for a user across all browsers.

Comment: I need to generate a unique identifier for an individual window tab. Setting a viewScope to a random number would work until the viewScope changes within a given tab session then I will have lost the unique identifier. What I would like to do is create a key of the DBRepID/userName/TabUniqueID/Timer that I would store in an applicationScope variable then if a user opens a new tab and tries opening the database I would know it is something I should block. When the browser opens a Tab does it assign it a name/number that I can access?

Comment: You are right, viewScope lives too short for your use case. I updated my answer with a promising approach.

Comment: This seems to be a very basic and potentially fatal problem how do others handle this? I can stop this between Browsers by creating an application scope with the 
var sessionID = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession().getId();
 
UserName/DBRepID/sessionID/Time and then block the opening in the second browser.
Multiple tabs in the same browser are so easy to get and the results can be severe.

Comment: I extended my answer's code to a complete solution. It does what you want: it allows only one open browser window/tab per user and database. This solution covers already multiple browsers as the generated random ids are unique across all browsers and window/tabs. It works per database too as application scope is unique per database already. The open window/tab tells server every 5 seconds "I am alive" and after 7 seconds of no answer from this window/tab other window/tabs can take over.

Comment: as usual great solution. As with most great solutions it is 'simple' and clean. I used the applicationScope variable in a document locking process and it works great. By adding the tabID to it becomes the total solution to a very serious problem. Without having to go outside basic javascript. Beautiful! 
Just have to add the customControl to two XPages and I'm in business. I think you should post this as a snippet on OpenNTF

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'll post it as an XSnippet.

Comment: after a bit of work I created a xpStart.xsp containing the UniqueBrowser cc. This page acts as a 'gate keeper' because users would frequent arrive from an email link and would have URL params that govern where they go and what page to open. Then my actual functional XPages need the custom control as well to just keep the 'lock' timer updated. I was having trouble when the user hit xpMain.xsp because it set some sessionScope variables when the page loads, so xpMain.xsp would be loaded in two browser instances but blocked from going further in the second one. Using the xpStart page solved that.

Answer (score 0):

There is the SessionID cookie which is unique for the browser. I believe it's passed as part of the partial refresh information.

Just bear in mind that the SessionID would be the same for multiple windows of the browser. I'm not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: You get the sessionID in SSJS with http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-sessionid-in-ssjs

Comment: That helps a bit but is there an unique identifier for a window in the same browser. Because I use sessionScope varibales to control where I am and what is happening opening another session in the same browser can lead to very unpredictable results.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann is that unique for each window in the same browser session?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is the same for all windows in same browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that have posted here. In actual fact there are two similar but different issues.

In the first instance it is to block multiple instances of the application in the same browser, and Sven's post answers that one.

The second issue is opening the same application in multiple browsers. In this case I am going to use an applicationScope variable appSession which is a Map with the key being UserName~DBRepID then two 'fields'

Time which is refreshed by a Client Side timer event which updates the time every "N" seconds.
sessionID = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession().getId();

In the before page loads (perhaps as a PhaseListener ??) I lookup appSession with the key UserName~RepID if the sessionID matches open the page. if the Time in appSession is time expired then set the time to the current time and set the sessionID to the current getID() and open the page. If not then open error page.
The sessionID has to have a timer on it so that if the user closes the browser or tab it will eventually time out. I'm using something like this for an XPage Document locking routine and it works well.

I have not put this all together yet but it looks to me as if it should get the job done. If anyone see a better way to do this I would be happy to hear.

Comment: I extended my answer's code to a complete solution. It does what you want: it allows only one open browser window/tab per user and database. This solution covers already multiple browsers as the generated random ids are unique across all browsers and window/tabs. It works per database too as application scope is unique per database already. The open window/tab tells server every 5 seconds "I am alive" and after 7 seconds of no answer from this window/tab other window/tabs can take over.