# "I am Alive" in single browser session

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

[How to stop a user from opening a new browser session in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426273/how-to-stop-a-user-from-opening-a-new-browser-session-in-xpages)

In the answer to this posting Knutt added a really nice bit of code that stops a user from opening multiple instances of the same application in a browser. This works very well in a web browser, but when the App is opened in a Notes Client the screen flashes every 5 seconds as the "I am Alive" code is executed. I have set the database in the Notes Preferences to run on server, but this does not seem to help. 
Does anyone have any ideas how to, fix this?

Comment: Do you need this functionality for XPiNC too or is it just fine to switch it of there. You could do it with a test `@ClientType() == 'Notes'`.

Comment: I was considering do that but have much the same issue with opening multiple copies of the same App in the Notes Client. I understand that there is a Database setting that causes the the application to run on the server which I believe just forces the Notes Client to run in the Notes Web Browser, but I can't find it. I'm assuming that if it runs in the embedded browser that it would perform the same as in FireFox/Chrome directly.

Comment: Found the Notes DB Property "Run server Based XPages directly on the server" and that does not help. So perhaps I need to switch it off for the Notes Clients but I would prefer not

Comment: Just tested XPiNC with Notes 8.5.3 and 9.0.1: screen doesn't flash. What is on your XPage? Do you have UI elements in panel "browserTabControl"?

Comment: I'm going to have to strip it down and test it at a simpler level.

Comment: I removed the UniqueTab completely and still have the issue so is not related. Will have to track down what is going wrong.

Comment: This code would keep the server session active so would not need any other keep session active code on the page?

Comment: Yes, no need for other keep session alive code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a conflict between two other processes that were causing the issue. The frequency happened to be very similar to the 5 -7 seconds used in "I am Alive". It is working as intended with no code change needed.